# why do I get a segmentation fault in this string copy program?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I wrote a string copy program using pointer,but it got a segmentation fault,don't know why.

Thanks

here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void strcp(char *s,char *t){
   while(*s++=*t++)
        ;
     }

void main(){
  char *d="this is destination";    
  char *s="this is source";  
  strcp(d,s);
  while(d++){
     printf("%s  " ,*d);
   }

    return;
  }
```

Comment: Your second parameter, as well as both of the literals, should be `const char *` (or `char[]` for the literals). Your main function would be better off as `int main()` as well. You probably don't want the while loop to print, either. Just `printf("%s  ", d);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` is pointing to a string literal it is undefined behavior to write to a string literal. You could alternatively define `d` as follows:

```
char d[]="this is destination";
```

Also you need to fix the `printf` and loop from this:

```
while(d++){
  printf("%s  " ,*d);
}
```

to this:

```
printf("%s  " ,d);
```

and you can remove the loop. Finally, `main` should always return an `int`:

```
int main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you weren't passing in literals, if t is longer than s then your pointer runs off the end.